# manipulating radio box selection with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i'm trying to do a poll but i designed it without any radio box in it. So i decided to make the selection being highlighted with a different background color, all is done with jquery.

I set the display of the radio box to none so that it wouldn't show, gave each a unique ID. Here's the script.

```
<form action="v_poll.php" method="post">
<ul class="voting">
<li class="voting votetext"><input type="radio" name="voting" value="a1" style="display:none;" id="a1"><a onClick="vote('a1')"Answer 1</a></li>
<li class="voting votetext"><input type="radio" name="voting" value="a2" style="display:none;" id="a2"><a onClick="vote('a2')">Answer 2</a></li>
<li class="voting votetext"><input type="radio" name="voting" value="a3" style="display:none;" id="a3"><a onClick="vote('a3')">Answer 3</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="id" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vote(TheValue) {
GetElementById(TheValue).checked=true;
}
</script>
```

But when i checked the value of the radio box with $_POST['voting'], it is blank. Not the value assigned to the radio box. Anything i'm doing wrong?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please, **please** don't use javascript for this, it's *completely* supported with native HTML, you're only breaking non javascript consumers without any reason here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without javascript as well, using a [`<label>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) with `for="id"` instead of `<a>`, like this:

```
<li class="voting votetext">
  <input type="radio" name="voting" value="a1" style="display:none;" id="a1">
  <label for="a1">Answer 1</label>
</li>
```

This is nothing new/HTML5 or anything, any browser IE6+, and probably older will support this.

Answer (score 3):

```
GetElementById(TheValue).checked=true;
```

should instead be:

```
document.getElementById(TheValue).checked=true;
```